# How to use localization with String.Format

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I work on an Asp.net Core MVC website with localization and
I've a text to display with variables inside like :

```
@{var item = "car"}
<h1>Max's @item is blue</h1>
```

but in french it's

```
@{var item = "la voiture"}
<h1>@item de Max est bleue</h1>
```

So the words's order change, I've try :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
    <h1>@String.Format(Localizer["Max's {0} is blue"],@item)</h1>
```

with a traduction :

```
    Max's {0} is blue => {0} de Max est bleu
```

but I've an error :

```
FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Try with `Localizer["Max's {0} is blue"].Value,@item`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Camilo Terevinto's solution work perfectly. here's the full solution if it can help anyone :

**View :**

```
@model Project.Models.item
    <h1>@String.Format(Localizer["Max's {0} is {1}"].Value, Model.Name, Model.Color)</h1>
```

**Resx :**

```
Max's {0} is {1} => {0} de Max est {1}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 @Localizer["My Format {0}", myValue]
```

It solves the problem because that is the syntax for localizer with parameters.

Comment: This answer was flagged by someone as low quality because while it provides a code snippet that may solve the problem stated in the question, it does not explain *why* it solves the problem. In the future, please add detail to your answer that shows why the code you post applies to the question being asked. Thank you.